# Is it possible to support both Facebook Login and Google Plus login in the same iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, integration, google-plus

I integrated Google plus login in my iOS App. But I dont know how to add FB integration in the same app. Is it possible to use both logins in the same app?

Comment: Yes it is possible to add. same way as u are adding  the google plus

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since u are added the Google plus, every thing is same for adding the FB login

[image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
 {

  return ([FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url] || [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]);

 }
```

hope this Helps :)

Comment: then what about URLTypes?

Comment: same way u did for g+ add another item 0 -> g+, add one more item 1 ->Fb

Comment: I need both SDK`s, If i replaced fbID then it Google plus is not working if i used google plus fb not working how can i use both id`s?

Comment: no u dont need to replace anything hear hear add one more object to URL scheme array and set there separately

Comment: let me know if u are facing any problem

Comment: URL Schemes are Ok its working fine, What about URL identifier?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41410/discussion-between-shan-and-anand)

Comment: Its crash when you press cancel button on web view

Comment: @AlizainPrasla : it is working fine  ... i think, check your code where might be the wrong

Answer (score 1):

@Anand You can use FBConnect SDK and nothing add in this method

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

just use that sdk and enjoy....)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can support both, but each is configured slightly differently. **For Google+** you will register your bundle identifier in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) when you create the client ID for your app. The `plist` URL Scheme's value should also be set to this identifier.

More information:

- http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/06/common-issues-with-google-sign-in-on-ios.html

You'll need to add another `URL Type` to your `plist` **for Facebook**. Its URL Scheme's value will be your facebook application's ID preceded by `fb`.

More information:

> Finally, you need to place the Facebook app ID in two places in your
>   application's main .plist file, and add a reference to your app's
>   Display Name. Create a key called FacebookAppID with a string value,
>   and add the app ID there. Next, create a key called
>   FacebookDisplayName with a string value, and add the Display Name you
>   configured in the App Dashboard.
>
> Create an array key called URL types with a single array sub-item
>   called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your app ID prefixed
>   with fb. This is used to ensure the application will receive the
>   callback URL of the web-based OAuth flow.

Source:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#configure

Of course, this merely sets up the `plist`. You'll also need to implement all of the required functionality for both, including the login buttons, calling the FB and G+ APIs, and handling all necessary events. You should read the respective docs for complete information, but the two will play nicely together once everything is in place.

For example, here's one way to handle login app-switching for both libraries:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url] || 
           [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url 
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication 
                         annotation:annotation];

}
```